# Connecting to Redshift Data Using Python - Error: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block

Tags: python, sql, amazon-redshift, psycopg2

I am trying to connect the Redshift data using Python (Jupyter Notebook). after running the last line, am getting this error:

> InFailedSqlTransaction: current transaction is aborted, commands
> ignored until end of transaction block

could you please help me here.

```
import psycopg2
con=psycopg2.connect(dbname= 'TBD', host='TBD', 
port= 'TBD', user= 'TBD', password= 'TBD')
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute("SELECT site_id FROM dfa_std")
```

Comment: do you need a semi-colon at the end of your SQL? Possibly single quotes around the table name? (not sure on that one).  Also add cur.fetchall() at the end

Comment: I've tried with and without semi-colon, also with and without single quotes, did not work!

Comment: are you sure your conn parameters are correct?

Comment: yep, when am running the first and second lines, there is no error.

import psycopg2

con=psycopg2.connect(dbname= 'TBD', host='TBD', 

port= 'TBD', user= 'TBD', password= 'TBD')

Comment: are there any other lines before that error? about connection failing? can you see whether you can connect (from the same ip) using psql command line tool and if not - what error?

Comment: I am able to connect with the same IP using DBeaver.

Comment: that's so weird! I got connected to the database (I removed close.fetchell() ) but the problem is taking too much time! is this something normal?

Answer (score 0):

As well as `psycopg2` you need have `sqlalchemy` and [`ipython-sql`](https://github.com/catherinedevlin/ipython-sql) installed in the Notebook server's Python.

Create a file with your Redshift endpoint and credentials:

```json
echo "{
  \"user_name\": \"my_user\",
  \"password\": \"my_pswd\",
  \"host_name\": \"my_cluster_endpoint\",
  \"port_num\": \"5439\",
  \"db_name\": \"my_db\"
}" > my.creds
```

Then try this in your notebook:

```
import sqlalchemy
import psycopg2
import simplejson

%reload_ext sql
%config SqlMagic.displaylimit = 25

with open("my.creds") as fh:
    creds = simplejson.loads(fh.read())
connect_to_db = "postgresql+psycopg2://" + \
                creds["user_name"] +':'+ creds["password"] +'@'+ \
                creds["host_name"] +':'+ creds["port_num"] +'/'+ creds["db_name"];
%sql $connect_to_db
%sql SELECT current_user, version();
```

Expected output:

```
'Connected: my_user@my_db'

current_user | version
 my_user     | PostgreSQL 8.0.2 on i686-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by GCC gcc (GCC) 3.4.2 20041017 (Red Hat 3.4.2-6.fc3), Redshift 1.0.24238
```

Comment: I need to create that file on "Jupyter Notebook"?

Comment: Yes, you can run that in a cell. Each notebook runs within a folder context and can read/write to the local disk.